# INSERT a record into a table in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I am using SQLAlchemy and I want to insert a record into the database. I am running my application in Flask-Restful

model.py

```
class User(BaseModel, db.Model):

    """Model for the user table"""
    __tablename__ = 'usertable'
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
```

signup.py

```
from app.models import db, User

class Register(Resource):
    def post(self):
        email = request.json['email']
        password = request.json['password']
        db.session.add(User.email = 'test@gmail.com') // Here, I am not sure
        return email
```

I want to add `email` and `password` into the table `usertable` . When I am running the code, error is showing, `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression` . What is the recommended way to add a record in SQLAlchemy ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
db.session.add(User.email = 'test@gmail.com')
```

Try:

```
user = User(email=email, password=password)
db.session.add(user)
db.session.commit()
```

However, it's not a good idea to store a plain text password in your database. You should modify your User model to store a hashed password instead.

Comment: I think you can assume the password is already hashed client-side, but I agree its a good practice nontheless